# Fetching API data inside express route returns undefined when using then or await

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, undefined, router

#### The problem

I'm creating an express server which fetches currency exchange rates from an API. In the route I fetch those exchange rates via a helper function and I then want to return them in the response body on the format `{data: rates, status: 200}`.

However, the only thing returned from the route is `{status: 200}` as the exchange rates are undefined (pending promise). The fetch goes through successfully, i.e is not caught in the catch clause nor are the default results returned. They key 'rates' also exists.

I don't understand **why** this is undefined nor how to fix it as I am awaiting the response from the service before returning from the route. I've also tried encapsulating the router response in a `.then` clause instead of using await but I encounter the same problem.

#### API service fetch

```js
require("isomorphic-fetch");
const { DEFAULT_RATES } = require("../resources/other/default_exchange_rates");

// Documentation: https://currencyfreaks.com/documentation.html
let domain = "https://api.currencyfreaks.com/";

/*
 * Retrieve exchange rates from USD to other currencies.
 * Return object format: {EUR: "2.0293", XXX: "0.55736", ...}
 */

exports.getExchangeRates = async () => {
  return await (
    fetch(`${domain}latest?apikey=${process.env.EXCHANGE_RATE_API_KEY}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status > 200) {
          return DEFAULT_RATES;
        }
        let api_response = res.json();
        return api_response.rates; 
      })
      // Catch parse error
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  );
}
```

#### Route

```js
const service = require("../services/currency_api");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rates = await service.getExchangeRates();
    return res.status(200).send({ data: rates, status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.stats(400).send({ error: "An error occurred", status: 400 });
  }
});

module.exports = router;

/*
 Postman test response:
 {
   "status": 200
 }

*/
```

Comment: Try using `res.json` instead of `res.send`

Comment: Already tried that :/

Comment: Then try removing `return` from `router.post` callback and see if that works

Comment: Made no difference. However I have noticed that if I return res.json() in getExchangeRates I do get the full API data object in postman. Why is that?

Comment: Oh right, `response.json()` in fetch returns a promise and you `await` for it, that's why it works

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that but I have resolved the issue by adding a second .then clause in the fetch that extracts the rates from the data. Would you know why this works and the other one doesn't?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change callback containing:

```
let api_response = res.json();
```

To:

```
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status > 200) {
      return DEFAULT_RATES;
    }
    return res.json();

  })
  .then(api_response => api_response.rates);
```

The `fetch` `response.json()` method returns a promise, so to get the actual value you either have to await for it or return the promise and add another `.then` to wait for `res.json()` to resolve.

In turn, when you're not waiting for `res.json()` your promise resolves to `undefined`(`api_response` is a promise, and `rates` is `undefined`), and then `data` is also `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The working solution using baldrs answer

```js
exports.getExchangeRates = () =>{
  let url = `${domain}latest?apikey=${process.env.EXCHANGE_RATE_API_KEY}`;
  return (
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status > 200) {
          return DEFAULT_RATES;
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => data.rates)

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  );
}
```